# jQuery - Pass variable to click function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple jQuery question with the following code:

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#changeText").click(function() {
        $.get("test.php", { sectid: "1"},
            function(data){
            $("#textBox").html(data);
        });
    });
    });
 </script>
```

My HTML is as follows:

```
<a id="changeText" href="#">Change</a>
<div id="textBox">This text will be changed to something else</div>
```

I'd like to pass a variable into the `.click` function in place of "1" but can't seem to get the syntax correct. Can someone point me the right direction?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just use the variable name, for example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#changeText").click(function() {
    var myVariable = "1";
    $.get("test.php", { sectid: myVariable },
        function(data){
        $("#textBox").html(data);
    });
  });
});
```

Or if it's a value from something for example:

```
$.get("test.php", { sectid: $(this).attr("something") },
```

Comment: I think he wants to pass a variable to the click function when it's called.

Comment: @Rocket - in that case it'd look the same, just with the `var MyVariable = "1";` moved outside/before.

Comment: @Nick: Yeah, I know.  I was just sayin'.

Comment: Sorry, bear with me... I want to pass it through the html code so if I had multiple links I could change the link at the href and pass it through to the php code on the back end. If I bury this function in another function it doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: @Seth - can you give an example of the markup, and what from it you want to pass?  If for example you wanted the current clicked link's `href`, it'd be `$(this).attr("href")`, or `this.href` if you didn't care about normalization in IE.

Comment: ok, i can use the following html: <a id="changeText" href="#2">Change</a>  to pass the variable to myVariable = $(this).attr("href"); but if I change the href to 2 instead of #2, then it follows the link when clicked.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the variable before the function is called.  Then read it's value after.

Example (using jQuery's `.data`):

```
$("#changeText").data('sectid', '1');

 $("#changeText").click(function() {
    $.get("test.php", {sectid: $(this).data('sectid')},
        function(data){
          $("#textBox").html(data);
    });
});
```

Comment: You can use `$.data(this, 'sectid')` which is much cheaper...but even that seems like overkill, why would you store a known thing via `.data()` on an ID element (which *should* be unique)?

Comment: @Nick: Yeah, I guess it is overkill, but it's the first thing that I could think of.  Also, he wants the sectid to be a variable, and I wanted my answer to be different from yours :-P